# launching a dos command in IPython 4 without blocking IPython user interface

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I whish to launch a dos command from IPython 4.0, so that this command doesn't block IPython interface, which can than execute the next cell immediately, without caring of the result of the launched process. Is it Possible ?

My current fail attempt is (for example)

!start cmd /C python -c "import pyqtgraph.examples; pyqtgraph.examples.run()"